# Convert for loop into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

```py
for timeprojection in range(100):
   for term in range(8):
       zerocouponbondprice[timeprojection,term] = zerocouponbondprice[timeprojection-1,term-1]*cashflow[timeprojection,term]
```

How can I convert something like this into `numpy` array form, so that I can reduce two for loop to increase the speed? (If `timeprojection` and `term` are dynamic numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the numpy array from a nested list comprehension

```py
import numpy as np

zerocouponbondprice = np.array([[k * l for k,l in zip(i,j)] for i,j in zip(zerocouponbondprice, cashflow[1:])])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question right, you can replace the two loops / ranges by using appropriate indexing. A simplified example:

```
import numpy as np

# these would be your input arrays zerocouponbondprice and cashflow:
arr0, arr1 = np.ones((10,10)), np.ones((10,10))

# these would be your ranges:
idx0, idx1 = 3, 9

# now you can do the calculation as simple as
arr0[idx0:idx1, idx0:idx1] = arr0[idx0-1:idx1-1, idx0-1:idx1-1] + arr1[idx0:idx1, idx0:idx1]

print(arr0)
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```